# How to make interactive plot in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, plotly, interactive

I am trying to plot timeseries data on an interactive plot, such that i can zoom in the data for detailed observations.
My main code for basic plot is,

```
using IterableTables, DataFrames, CSV, Dates, TimeSeries, Plots

myfile="test2.csv"
dmft = dateformat"d/m/yyyy HH:MM:SS"
println(dmft)
df = DataFrame(CSV.File(joinpath(@__DIR__,myfile); dateformat=dmft))
df2 = filter(row -> row[:Date] <= Dates.DateTime("2020-10-15T00:06:00"), df)

x = convert(Matrix, df[:, [:Date]])
y = convert(Matrix, df[:, [:Col3]])
```

#I placed usual plot function which I have removed for this block`

Please someone suggest how can I plot these two columns on an interactive plot?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The plotlyjs backend of Plots.jl allows interactive zooming, etc.
The code should be (I cannot test it now):

```
using Plots
plotlyjs()
plot(x, y)
```

I use this often in a Pluto notebook, where you can e.g. add PlutoUI elements (like sliders, selection boxes) for interactive filtering / data exploration.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that a lot of the standard plotly functions (buttons, animation, etc.) is missing from Plotly.jl? Can't find mention of it in the documentation, but plotly's never been fully documented.

Answer (score 0):

For interactive behavior similar to Matlab on Plots.jl, run `default(show=true)`. Alternatively, you could switch to PyPlot which has the same features in a more intuitive manner. If you need something further (ie manipulation of parameters), see [Iteract.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGizmos/Interact.jl)